# Scratch org. default workflow user

Tags: deployment, salesforcedx, continuous-integration, ci

Is it possible to programmatically set the default workflow user in a scratch org?

My use is that I'm spinning up a fresh scratch org. as part of my CI pipeline. I could (and currently do) use a sandbox but I'd like to see if it's possible to do this using scratch orgs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, as of the time of this answer, there is no public API that allows you to set this value. You would necessarily need to change it manually each time.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. I've posted an idea: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000PYroQAG

Answer (score 8):

For your Scratch Orgs, you can use the `DefaultWorkflowUser` feature in your `project-scratch-def.json` file to set the value with the scratch org user:

```
...
"features": ["DefaultWorkflowUser"],
...
```

The feature value is documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm), even though it's not explicitly explained what it's doing.

Comment: +1 Nice find! I presume that this is a relatively new feature?

Comment: I never really noticed this one before (also didn't had to use it, that may be why), but according to the doc it's there since Winter '18.

Comment: That's odd. That means my answer was wrong all along, but I'm pretty sure I checked the docs. Maybe they mean Winter '19? Or maybe the docs just were not clear enough. Either way, glad to know there's a solution to this.

Comment: Definitely a doc shortcoming. The features and settings for scratch org defs that don't correspond directly to the MDAPI have no documentation of their functionality beyond their names.

Comment: Unfortunately now broken by Salesforce's [latest security change](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000782250&type=1)... it would be fine if Salesforce actually only required this on production orgs. This breaks our CI pipeline. #sigh#